# 'RunTime:loadLib: libopencv_java430.so (failed) probably dependent libs missing' error while running sikuli test script in Red had 7.6

Tags: java

Used maven project:
My Automation sikuli script:
package Sikuli1.DesktopProject;
Error logs:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/rajatesh/.Sikulix/SikulixLibs/libopencv_java430.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
[error] RunTime:loadLib: libopencv_java430.so (failed) probably dependent libs missing:
/home/rajatesh/.Sikulix/SikulixLibs/libopencv_java430.so: /home/rajatesh/.Sikulix/SikulixLibs/libopencv_java430.so: file too short
[error] Save your work, correct the problem and restart the IDE!
[error] see: https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/wiki/macOS-Linux:-Support-Libraries-for-OpenCV-4
TERMINATING: problem with native library: libopencv_java430.so
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    at org.sikuli.script.Pattern.(Pattern.java:128)   at Sikuli1.DesktopProject.SikuliProject.main(SikuliProject.java:11)
Caused by: org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: fatal: problem with native library: libopencv_java430.so   at org.sikuli.script.support.RunTime.terminate(RunTime.java:1140)   at org.sikuli.script.support.RunTime.libsLoad(RunTime.java:1285)    at org.sikuli.script.support.RunTime.loadLibrary(RunTime.java:1434) at org.sikuli.script.Finder$Finder2.(Finder.java:538)
... 2 more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install opencv Java library. Note that you are using Redhat while Sikuli 2 works out of the box with Ubuntu flavors. So you need install required libs by yourself.